# How to clean up paint "air bubbles" after double sided tape?

Tags: walls, paint, rental

My partner and I are renting a place for the first time ever. We decorated the walls with some posters using double sided tape and double sided foam tape.
We like rearranging the place a bit, so we wanted to move the posters around, and ended up "bubbling" the paint off the walls. Thankfully nothing has been stripped, but there are pretty ugly wrinkles on the wall now... Pictures attached.

Also, we live in the Philippines so we don't really have access to computer color-matched paint, but I am an artist and can do pretty good myself.
[image: Regular double sided tape]

[image: Double sided foam tape]

[image: The worst one so far]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That paint was poorly bonded to begin with. It shouldn't have done that. However, now that it has you need to do a few things:

1. Cut around the bubble and remove the loose paint. Use a sharp utility knife and light pressure, just enough to score the paint. Pull *sideways* to avoid removing more.
2. Skim the depression with spackle or joint compound. Use a wide steel taping knife and press firmly, flexing the blade against the wall.
3. When that's dry, scrape lightly with the blade and skim again if needed.
4. Sand lightly to knock down any bumps or lines.
5. Prime to seal the patch, then paint.